# VSFTPD uploaded file permissions

Tags: permissions, ftp, file-permissions, vsftpd

Let me first say that there are loads of topics regarding this, and I am sure i have seen them all by now. Still non of the solutions seem to help.

I installed vsftpd. created a user ftp-data. Now I need that files uploaded by user ftp-data would have 755 permissions. Solving this should be as easy as adding:

```
local_umask=002
file_open_mode=0755
```

but that did not help, then I have tried a number of variations of this, still did not help.

The I added:

```
chmod_enable=YES
```

still did not help.

At the moment I think that I am missing something very simple and obvious, just cant find it. Maybe someone could help me to find what I am missing.

This is my config file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=NO
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
listen=YES
local_root=/var/www/ftp-gallery
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

EDIT: Solved it. It was a problem with the client I was using. The FTP client itself was changing permissions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `local_umask` and `file_open_mode` as you describe works as expected on a system I have to hand.

Did you remember to restart the vsftpd service after making the changes ?

Comment: yes I have restarted /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart is what i used

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem, my files were uploaded with permission of `600` and folders were with `700`.

I had to change the **local_umask** to `022` to get the right permissions to be set when the files are uploaded over `FTP over TLS` encryption.

```
# in etc/vsftpd.conf
local_umask=022
```

This made the permision set for uploaded files to be `644` and folder to be `755`
Then of course, i had to restart the vsftpd service using

`systemctl restart vsftpd`